# installing apache2 on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, ubuntu-12.04

My apache2 was working properly on ubuntu.
But now it shows following error when I restart it.

- Restarting web server apache2                                                apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
  apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName

I tried uninstalling and then reinstalling it..

I edit my config file and added ServerName localhost

though the error is gone but i am still unable to run the localhost on the browser

Comment: is it running okay with http://127.0.0.1?

Comment: no its not running ok with 127.0.0.1.. i checked through sudo netstat -lnptu its not showing apache there... though i have reinstalled apache2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that your FQDN is set correctly.

Try the following

1. edit /etc/hostname, to e.g. localhost
2. run : hostname -F /etc/hostname
3. edit /etc/hosts accordingly
4. /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Answer (score 5):

Edit /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
and add the following line

```
ServerName localhost
```

now restart apache

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thank. I did the following edit. now i am getting this on restart 
* Restarting web server apache2                                         [ OK ]


but when i run local host on my web browser I am still unable to run  the local host

Comment: run "sudo netstat -lnptu" and see in which port apache is listening.

Comment: I did sudo netstat -lnptu .. It does not shows apache on any of the port. I have tried installing it again and again. it runs the first time when i install it but the second time i refresh it stops working.. I install phpmyadmin.. it gets installed without asking the root password..

Comment: Checkout the error logs and see whats happening. " sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log"

Comment: Thank you .. lot.. really great full to you.. found the error.. and removed it

Answer (score 1):

```
Open Terminal (Ctrl + Alt + t)
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
(you can also use any editor like nano vi )
(By default httpd.conf file will be blank. Now, simply add the following line to the file)
ServerName localhost
(Save the file and close gedit)
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the httpd.conf file

> sudo vim /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

It's blank file and you need to add:

> ServerName localhost

to httpd.conf. Then restart the apache.

> apache2ctl restart